# CORS Issue with AjaxSubmit vs. Standard Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cors

I have two applications that communicate with each other on Google's App Engine.  They are running under a different domain.  I have enabled CORS by using the following in Python:

```
self.response.headers.add_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
```

This works perfectly when I use a call such as the following in JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "https://theurl.com",
            cache: false,
            data: {"auth":authCode,},
            success: function(data)
            {
                success stuff
            }
        }) // end of ajax call
```

However, if I convert the above to use ajaxSubmit I get a CORS error:

```
$("#secureForm").ajaxSubmit(
    {
        type:"POST",
        url: "https://theurl.com",
        cache: false,
        success: function(data)
        {
            same success stuff as above
        } 
    }) // end of ajax submit
```

Obviously the two methods post slightly differently but they go to the exact same place with different results.  I am looking to use ajaxSubmit in order to ensure that the parameters I am passing are not viewable in programs such as Firebug, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's an internal server error in your Python application.
Most internal server errors don't deliver CORS headers as the server stops before your header is set.

As you can see the jQuery ajaxSubmit does work with CORS filters:
http://jsfiddle.net/8JJC8

However you could also use [jQuery.serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/):

```
$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "https://theurl.com",
        cache: false,
        data: $('#secureForm').serialize(),
        success: function(data)
        {
            // success stuff
        }
    })
```

Comment: Thank you for your time.  CORS does work with Python.  I answered my own question above that my issue was a bad auth code.  Dumb mistake on my part.

Comment: As I said an application error in your Python code ;)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is my own stupid fault.  I was sending an incorrect auth code and my Python only sets CORS when the data being sent is valid.  Like I said, stupid mistake on my side.  To be clear, from the messages above, Python DOES send appropriate CORS headers in just way I described in my OP.  In my case, I just needed to invoke it with the right auth code to begin with....

Incidentally, using ajaxSubmit doesn't solve the problem that led me here anyway.  The parameters can still be seen with Firebug....